# Render bean errors and exception in template

Tags: grails

I have controller that checks if a `Command Object` is valid or not. If it isn't, I render an error `template`:

```
if (!cmdObj.validate()) {
    render (status: 400, template:'error', model: [errorObj: cmdObj])
    return
}
```

Then in the error `template`, I have the following code to render all of the errors from the bean

```
<div>
    <g:hasErrors bean="${errorObj}">
        <div class="error-messages">
            <g:renderErrors bean="${errorObj}"/>   
        </div>
    </g:hasErrors>
</div>
```

This works fine. However, I want to use the same error `template` when I handle exceptions. For example, in the same controller, I have a method to handle exceptions:

```
def handleMyCustomException(MyCustomException e) {
    render (status: 500, template:'error', model: [errorObj:e])
}
```

This doesn't work because the `Exception` isn't a bean that Grails can use to render errors.

Is there a way that I can reuse my error `template` for beans that are invalid and for exceptions?

I'm using Grails 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple way I came up with to have the template display both `Bean` errors and `Exceptions`

```
<div>
    <g:if test="${exception}">
        <div class="error-messages">
            ${exception.message}   
        </div>
    </g:if>
    <g:elseif test="${errorObj}">
        <g:hasErrors bean="${errorObj}">
            <div class="error-messages">
                <g:renderErrors bean="${errorObj}"/>   
            </div>
        </g:hasErrors>
    </g:elseif>
</div>
```

Then in the exception handler:

```
render (status: 500, template:'error', model: [exception:e])
```